# How to use auto keyword in C++

Tags: c++

I have C++ code with a type `auto`:

```
auto T = reads a JSON
```

I need to print the content of the `T` using

```
cout << T << endl;
```

It is not working. Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: `auto` is not a type, it asks the compiler to *guess* the type from context. What *exactly* is the `reads a JSON` part? Which header files and libraries are you using for JSON? Which compiler, which operating system, which compilation flags? Please **edit your question** to improve it *a lot* !

Answer (score 2):

With C++11, you can declare a variable or an object without specifying its speciﬁc type by using auto.1 For example:

```
   auto i = 42; // i has type int 
    double f(); 
    auto d = f(); // d has type double
```

The type of a variable declared with auto is deduced from its initializer. Thus, an initialization is required:

auto i; // ERROR: can’t dedulce the type of i

Additional qualiﬁers are allowed. For example:

static auto vat = 0.19;

Using auto is especially useful where the type is a pretty long and/or complicated expression. For example:

```
vector<string> v; ... auto pos = v.begin(); // pos has type        vector<string>::iterator
auto l = [] (int x) -> bool { // l has the type of a lambda ..., // taking an int and returning a bool };
```

In short auto can deduce any type .Your program is not working because it is possible that it is not able to parse JSON or compiler is old (where auto is not supported .Can you specifically let me know the error you got ?

Comment: Um, although it's not completely clear, I think the problem is with the stream insertion, not the `auto` itself.

Comment: Agreed , same thing i have pointed .Either he is using old compiler or problem with fetching data .In either case problem is not clear enough

Answer (score 0):

`auto` in C++ means "set variable type for type of initialization expression", in your case whatever that "reads a JSON" expression returns. You cannot output that type to `std::cout` because `operator<<` is not defined for such type, there could be many possible reasons as operator not provided, you suppose to use something else, missing header etc. Solution would depend on actual type.

Answer (score 0):

Ok ! Before telling you how to use `auto`, I must tell you it's one of the best features of `C++11` & has made `C++` even more efficient by :-

1. Reducing amount of code
2. Enforcing initialization
3. Increasing genericity (In C++17)

Firstly `auto` has only 1 job. It will deduce the type of an object by the value passed to it. For ex :-

```
auto x = 5;
```

This means that `x` is an integer whose value is 5. Whenever you are using `auto` you must initialize the variable (which is a good thing) & you cannot use auto on multiple types in a statement. For ex :-

```
auto x;  // illegal ! x isn't initialized so compiler cannot dduce it's type
auto z=5, y=7;  // legal because z & y are both integers
auto a=8, ch= 'c';  // illegal ! an integer & a character in a single statement, hence type deduction ambiguity
```

The cream of `auto` is not in intializing `int`, `char`, etc data types. It's more handy for `classes` like `iterators`. For ex :-

```
vector<int> v;
vector<int>::iterator i1 = v.begin();
auto i2 = v.begin();   // see how auto reduces the code length
```

This can be even more obvious in `for` loops :-

```
for (vector<int>::iterator i = v.begin(); i!=v.end(); ++i);
```

Can be reduced to :-

```
for (auto i = v.begin(), i!=v.end(); ++i);
```

If you are not happy with the above then this may inspire you to use `auto` :-

```
vector< map <int, vector<string> > >::iterator i1 = v.begin();  // where v is the vector of maps of ints & vectors of strings !!!!
auto i2 = v.begin();
```

The genericity I was talking about is in passing values to functions by `auto`. Like :-

```
void add (auto x, auto y)
{
    cout << x+y << '\n';
}
```

This is not possible in current standards & has been proposed for C++17. This is likely to increase the generic ability of the functions without the use of `templates`. However this syntax is possible for `lambda functions` :-

```
auto l = [](auto x, auto y) { return x+y; }   // legal from C++14 onwards
```

However be careful when using braces with lambda because you may think that :-

```
auto x = {5};
```

Is an integer but it is actually an `intializer_list<int>` type object. I can explain a hell lot about `auto` but I guess for now this is more than enough.

Comment: "increase the generic ability of the functions without the use of templates." Could you explain that ?