# C++ error two or more data types in declaration of variable

Tags: c++, auto

I ran the following C program and got `In` as the output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    auto int i = 0;
    if(++i)
        printf("In");
    else
        printf("Out");

    return 0;
}
```

But when I tried to run it as a C++ program by changing the header files and standard output, I got an error:

> jdoodle.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> jdoodle.cpp:6:14: error: two or more data types in declaration of ‘i'.
> 6 |     auto int i = 0;
> |              ^.
> jdoodle.cpp:7:10: error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope.
> 7 |     if(++i).
> |          ^

C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    auto int i = 0;
    if(++i)
        cout<<"In";
    else
        cout<<"Out";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have tried ```auto int i; i=0;``` but got the same error.

Comment: don't be surprised to get different outcomes. C is not C++ and C++ is not C.

Comment: C: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192547/where-is-the-c-auto-keyword-used

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages.  You need to treat them as such.  You wouldn't try compiling C# as C++.

Comment: C++: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34318218/how-to-use-auto-in-c

Comment: I suppose it would work in C++98, but since C++11 `auto` has had its meaning changed.

Comment: Its actually not quite clear what the question is exactly. Why C and C++ are different? What is `auto` in C++? How to declare an `int` with automatic storage?

Comment: As a side note, the storage class `auto` has been meaningless and obsolete for at least a quarter of a century (so probably since before you were born). This is why C++ could decide to change `auto` to denote a type instead.

Answer (score 2):

In the C++ program, for the line

```
auto int i = 0;
```

the [`auto` keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) is being used to automatically deduce the type of variable `i` from its initialized value if compiling with C++11 or later. However, the line also includes `int`, which is also declaring the type. You can't use both of them -- you get the same error if you write `double int i = 0;` (`i` can't be both a `double` and an `int`) or `int int i = 0;` (it's the same type but you're declaring the type twice). Choose one or the other, i.e. either

```
auto i = 0;
```

or

```
int i = 0;
```

You can see that it works with C++98 but not C++11 or C++14 online [here](http://cpp.sh/3y35r). Prior to C++11 [the `auto` keyword was a storage class specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration).

Comment: nitpick: I suggest a tiny rewording, because the `double int i = 0;` example can be misunderstood as `auto` getting resolved to `double` in OPs example. Either "deduce the type of variable i from its initialized value which is `int`" or use `int int i = 0;` to illustrate the issue

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I've tweaked it now. Hopefully it's clearer.

Answer (score 2):

In C, [`auto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration) is an obsolete keyword it inherited from B. It is either implicitly assumed, or illegal to specify. So, it's basically never used.

C++ inherited this keyword from C as is, and your code [would have compiled](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7843TY) under C++98. In C++11 this keyword was repurposed to be used for [implicit type deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto). It is now widely used but means something completely different and the way you tried to use it is illegal.

The point is, C and C++ are different languages. Writing code that compiles under C and C++ is difficult and requires care.